# VSTO Outlook Plugin - How to disable "Make Recurring" button on outlook 365 meeting window [Looking for idMso of that button)

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, appointment

I am looking for an option to disable "Make Recurring" button on outlook 365 meeting window. This is a new button with Outlook 365 for which I am unable to find out idMSO.

I can do for the ribbon "Recurrence" button however there is no references available for the "Make Recurring" button.

Does anyone know about this or any option to find it out?

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

That is not a ribbon button. The best what you could do is to replace the UI with a form region where you need to rebuild the whole UI under the ribbon from scratch. The `Replace-all` layout replaces the whole Outlook form with the form region. See [Create Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2022) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, for this purpose to go away from existing custom task pane approach and build up form region is not an option. Anything else you can suggest to identify that non ribbon button?

Comment: Do you see another controls in that area listed on the ribbon? You can try using [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) for detecting the control's state.

Comment: Seems recurring is the only one. Microsoft Active Accessibility doesn't seem to have support for C# and have to explore more to understand if that can really help.

Comment: As you can see there is no trivial way.